# Oracle 19C Installation not changing port in docker when running in aws ec2 instance

Tags: oracle, docker, amazon-ec2

I have setup my ec2 instance with Amazon Linux recently, after installing docker engine on top of it. I am trying to install oracle database 19C. I am using this image from docker hub - https://hub.docker.com/r/heartu41/oracle19c

After pulling the image to my ec2 instance, I am running this command,
docker run -d -p 1522:1522 -e ORACLE_PDB=orcl -e ORACLE_PWD=myPassword_1 --name oracle heartu41/oracle19c

After database creation, when I am trying to access my db via SQL Developer, I am getting this error: Status :
Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=CU+VDPsBSvq5qHjARSnh/w==)

I went into my ec2 instance and run netstat -an

[oracle@4efe2d8e171a ~]$ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5500            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43205           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1521            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:1521         172.17.0.2:51876        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:51876        172.17.0.2:1521         ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46954         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59300         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59926         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45999         0.0.0.0:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     112206   /var/tmp/.oracle/sEXTPROC1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     112207   /var/tmp/.oracle/s#27.1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     112209   /var/tmp/.oracle/s#27.2

Here, I can see port 1522 is not being used.
Is there some extra setting, if I want to use a different port than 1521